# Error compilando com.google.android.gms to 10.0.0

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, firebase

Actualizando las dependencias en Android studio me encuentro con el siguiente error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.>
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.0.

las dependencias de la siguiente forma.

```
   android {                                                                                                        
    compileSdkVersion 26                                                                                         
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"                                                                                   
    defaultConfig {                                                                                              
        applicationId "meditech.com.mx.meditech"                                                                 
        minSdkVersion 21                                                                                         
        targetSdkVersion 26                                                                                      
        versionCode 1                                                                                            
        versionName "1.0"                                                                                        
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"                               
        // Enabling multidex support.                                                                            
        multiDexEnabled true                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                            
    buildTypes {                                                                                                 
        release {                                                                                                
            minifyEnabled false                                                                                  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'                   
        }                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                            

    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     dependencies {                                                                                                   
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])                                                            
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {                                
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'                                      
    })                                                                                                           


    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'                                                                 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'                                                              
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'                                             
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'                                                                    
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'                                                               
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'                                                 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'                                                   
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'                                                           
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'                                                        
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'                                                           
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'                                                                               
}                                                                                                                

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estas teniendo es porque hay un conflicto de versiones de las dependencias de Google Play lo cual es un problema ya que los cambio entre versión y versión pueden romper funcionalidad o traer funcionamiento no esperado.

Para solucionar esto debes asegurarte que las **librerías de Google play (GMS)** y las **librerías de firebase** tengan la misma versión (11.4.0 al momento de esta respuesta) y que esten actualizadas como la versión del **plugin de GMS** que podrás encontrar en el build.gradle padre del proyecto ( la versión 3.1.0 al momento de esta respuesta y que tiene la misma version de google play que las librerías mencionadas arriba)